# where can i store user media files like image, video etc

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, amazon-s3, cloudinary

I making a social website with mern stack. I try, user media file in mongodb with base64 string but problem is that it is large.where can i  store user media files like image, video etc.

Comment: What about only storing **bucket URL** created by Amazon S3 in your database (i.e. http://s3.amazonaws.com/...)? You don't need anything else because you can always get list of files from Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, storing BLOB (image is one of them) in DB is a really bad practice and I'm glad people are noticing it as they go down the road.

A common practice is storing files in a file system and then storing the file path in the DB.

If you are using online services, then you may consider using an image CDN instead and storing the URL in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in file system  problem is that if 10000 user's use website and post own media stuff. Then automatically make 10000 folder in backend. But it is so bad. But what about Grid fs system in mongodb. And how facebook and twitter handle this problem.

Comment: GridFs is basically a workaround instead of a solution. Like the main issue of storing BLOB is that it slows down queries because each row is huge now. GridFs just like "OK, let me break down the large files into smaller chunks so that each query will be smaller". But what it didn't tell you is, that it is still considerably larger than plan text rows.

And yes, most enterprise-level applications use either their on-premise file system or CDN to store files.

And BTW, 10k concurrent access is not a big deal for a server-level storage solution.

Comment: Okay, I try this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Cloudinary. Not only will you be able to store your videos but you’ll be able to manipulate and reduce the size of your assets without compromising on their quality.  The good news is it’s free to get started

Comment: yeah, I use this service. I know very well about this service. but thanks for your reply.